# unable to access data from rails api in angularjs

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, rails-api

I am trying to create a simple todo api using rails-api gem and for frontend I am using AngularJS. When I send a get request to rails server from browser its giving the appropriate JSON response (e.g. http://localhost:3000/tasks) but when I try to access the same from angular using ***$http.get([http://localhost:3000/tasks)](http://localhost:3000/tasks)_)*** it is going to the failure handler function instead of success. What shall I do?

Here is my code

Tasks Controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tasks
  # GET /tasks.json
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all

    render json: @tasks
  end

  # GET /tasks/1
  # GET /tasks/1.json
  def show
    render json: @task
  end

  # POST /tasks
  # POST /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    if @task.save
      render json: @task, status: :created, location: @task
    else
      render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1.json
  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    if @task.update(task_params)
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1
  # DELETE /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy

    head :no_content
  end

  private

    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :completed, :order)
    end
end
```

Angular code

```
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', [
'$scope',
'$http',
function($scope,$http){
  $scope.test = 'Hello world!';

  $http.get('http://localhost:3000/tasks').then(function(response){
    $scope.tasks = response.data;
  },function(response){
    alert('error');
  })
}]);
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div>
      {{test}}
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="task in tasks">{{task.title}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

When I visit the HTML page it shows *error* as alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a **CORS** problem. Does your web service support CORS? If not, you can use tools like [rack cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors).